# How to install ubuntu software packages in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How to install ubuntu software packages (*.deb, *.tar.bz etc) in windows 7 without using virtual box or any other virtual pc softwares..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need **Cygwin**.Cygwin is a collection of tools that offer a Linux-like environment on Windows. It’s not a way to run existing Linux software on Windows — the software will have to be recompiled. However, much software has already been recompiled. Cygwin will give you a Linux-like terminal and command-line environment with many of the command-line programs you may already be used to.

pls check the link http://bit.ly/1fm3CUT

Answer (score 0):

You must search the correct install files for your operative system. You can't install Ubuntu software in a natural way on windows, like you need **wine** for do it on Ubuntu.